# HTML:IT redirects me to the same file not to Inscription.html

Tags: html, tags

as i said in the question this is my problem with redirecting to a file in my computer

```
<a href="../html/inscription.html">
        <input type="submit" class="button-2" value="Inscription">
        </a>
```

Comment: Why would you put a link around a submit button?

Comment: Note the whole thing is your question. You said something in your title, which doesn't make much sense. What is HTML:IT? Is it valid in that language to have a button nested in an anchor, because in HTML, it is not. Please [edit] your question after reading [ask]. Note there is no need to put tags in the title; we have the Tags box for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put a link around your submit button anymore, you have the form's action attribute for that.
Your code should be like:

```
<form action="inscription.html" method="post">
    <!-- Put the other inputs here -->
    <input type="submit" class="button-2" value="Inscription">
</form>
```